# French equivalents of "an inside day"

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

> Man, I'm beat from all the climbing and such. Today’s got to be just **an inside day**.

This is a humourous way of saying "being cooped up in the house all day by his/her own free will, spending a languid afternoon etc".

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in French?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bien sûr il y a beaucoup de façons d'exprimer cette idée en français mais je ne pense pas qu'il y en ait une qui soit perçue comme une expression toute faite.

Le plus simple c'est :

> (Cette escalade m'a crevé), aujourd'hui je reste à la maison.

> Aujourd'hui (journée) repos.

> Aujourd'hui (journée) farniente.

Bien que ces deux dernières n'impliquent pas qu'on ne bouge pas de la maison, juste qu'on ne fait pas grand chose, c'est plutôt l'équivalent de "today's a lazy day".

On exprimera souvent l'idée par la négative :

> Aujourd'hui je ne sors pas.

> Aujourd'hui je ne bouge pas (de chez moi, de la maison, de l'hôtel, de la chambre...)

> Je ne mets pas les pieds dehors (hors de la maison, hors de...)

Comment: Possibly worth noting that at least for me in North America, "inside day" is not an *expression toute faite* either. Easy enough to figure out, and natural-sounding, but not one you'd necessarily predict. The closest one that comes to mind is an "indoor recess" at school.

Comment: @LukeSawczak It isn't in British English either. It is used as an idiom only in financial circles where it has a precise technical meaning meaning (which I would not be able to explain!)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a correct answer but, the humourous way of saying "being cooped up in the house all day by his/her own free will, spending a languid afternoon etc." is:

> Aujourd'hui je reste enfermé  +(not necessary) "à la maison" or "chez moi"
>   (I stay locked)

Or

> Aujourd'hui je reste cloîtré +(necessary!) "à la maison" or "chez moi"

"cloîtré" is when you stay in a cloister (like a nun or a monk) that one is quite humourous the most commun use of this expression is when for example your freind has a lot of work and stays home and you say "il reste cloîtré chez lui à travailler".

You can add **toute la journée** (all day long) at the end of every case to support the message.

Answer (score 1):

Laure almost included it in her answer but anyway, here is an idiomatic expression, especially in this "Tour de France" period:

> *Aujourd'hui, c'est **journée de repos*** ! (today, it's day of rest!)

It doesn't carry the "at home" side though.